# I need to format data from a command in unix shell scripting and put it in an array/table.I have given my command below

Tags: shell, unix

```
`grep 'MOVING_DATA Phase' /tmp/$$.status | awk '{print $11}'`
```

this is my command and I am getting result like

```
"database"."table1"
"database"."table2"
"database"."table3"
.....
.....
"database"."tablen"
```

I want to remove the double quotes and remove the delimeter '.' and store database name and table names in an array.I would appreciate if the result is displayed in the form of a table.I am new to Unix.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of `grep` and use `gsub` awk function to remove `"` and `.`:

```
awk '/MOVING_DATA Phase/{gsub(/["]/, "", $11);sub(/\./, " ", $11);print $11}'` /tmp/$$.status
```

To create **BASH arrays**:

```
#!/bin/bash

tabArr=()
dbArr=()

while read -r db table; do
   tabArr+=("$table")
   dbArr+=("$db")
done < <(awk '/MOVING_DATA Phase/{gsub(/["]/, "", $11);sub(/\./, " ", $11);print $11}'` /tmp/$$.status)
```

Comment: I have to send the details of this database name and table name in a mail in a table format.Could you please help me how to display it as a table while sending mail

Comment: Sure you can use: **`awk '/MOVING_DATA Phase/{gsub(/["]/, "", $11);sub(/\./, " ", $11);print $11}' /tmp/$$.status | column -t`**

Comment: with some modifications i was able to remove quotes and delimit the text.`grep 'MOVING_DATA Phase' /tmp/$$.status |awk '{gsub(/["]/, "", $11);sub(/\./, " ", $11);print $11}'` but loading data into table is not working.I am getting error as no such file or directory exists.once i load data into these columns..how do i display it?

Comment: Can you let me know what is your full she'll script. So that I can investigate and suggest.

Comment: sorry for late reply..Basically what I am trying to do is get some lines from output logs, split the data into different columns like DBname, table name, size of data moved etc...all the information for these 3 columns get can be obtained from our logs using grep 'MOVING_DATA Phase' this command results something like XXXXXXXX MOVVING DATA Phase completed for XXXX "databasename"."tablename" XXXX bytes moved : 12345. now I want to get the input for my columns from this line and create a table structure which I can send over mail

Comment: Position of "databasename.tablename" is 11th and 12345 (bytes moved) is 18th from the beginning of the line.

Comment: @ManasaJ: I think these requirements need to be posted as a new question so that you can get help from all the SO experts.

Comment: But do you think it is fair to delete or un-accept after someone invests lot of time helping you out? Someone else might get benefited by this answer someday.